# Shortcode for Product Name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know that shortcode for product name in woocommerce. I want to add product name in the subject of some emails. But despite searching a lot, I could not find any shortcode to show product name. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 6):

WooCommerce doesn't have a shortcode for displaying a product name, however, you can easily create your own.

Example:

```
function displayProductName($item) {
    $productName = get_the_title($item['id']);
    return $productName;
}

add_shortcode('product_name', 'displayProductName');
```

Usage:

Add the above code to your `functions.php` file and then use `[product_name id="10"]` to output the product title, where `id` is the id of the product in question. The above example uses the `get_the_title()` in-built WordPress function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

More information on how to create shortcodes can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

Comment: Is it possible to have shortcode that does not require item id? I am actually trying to add the shortcode to a custom email which is sent to customer after item is shipped. Since the email is sent as soon as the status of item is changed to shipped, it wouldn't be possible for me to add Id to each email.

Comment: You can use a similar construct, `{product_title}`. What I recommend is taking a look at how the default WooCommerce emails are set up. There's one called `Completed order` which you could use. All the email templates can be customised (or new ones created). WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this as there is no shortcode for including the product's name in the email subject. You will need to add some code in your child theme's function.php file through FTP.

I've wrote this code that will hook to the new orders subject and will change the default on (the one from the WooCommerce setting's page) to the one below `New Customer Order (#Some order number) from Some On - date; Products: Product name1; Product name2`.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_the_new_order_email_subject', 1, 2);
function change_the_new_order_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {

    //get the products' name from the order
    $product_name = '';
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
        $product_name .= $item['name'] . "; ";

    }

    $subject = sprintf( 'New Customer Order (# %s) from %s %s - %s; Products: %s', $order->id, $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name, $order->order_date, $product_name );

    return $subject;
}
```

Please mind, that I haven't tested the code.

Comment: Ale's code above works. The $order->order_date includes time and second, so I would remove that from the code.